# AVPlayer play SKVideoNode video ,I just can not control the playback

Tags: sprite-kit, avplayer, skvideonode

I am using the SpriteKit to play video,this is my code to create the SKVideoNode from AVPlayer:

```
    func CreateVideoViewWithAVPlayer(player:AVPlayer)
{
    video = SKVideoNode(AVPlayer: player)
    let frameLayer=AVPlayerLayer(player: player)
    //video?. = CGRectMake(0, 0, 100, 100)
    video?.size = CGSize(width: 1024, height: 768)
    println(player.currentItem)

    video?.anchorPoint = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)
    video?.position = CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0)

    backgroundColor = SKColor.blackColor()
    self.addChild(video!)
}
```

And I create a AVPlayer give the function:

```
        let scene01 = GameScene(size: view.bounds.size)
    scene01.CreateVideoViewWithAVPlayer(player!)
```

But When I call this  "player.play()" ,I just show the first frame and not going any more.  but if I use the "video" in the "CreateVideoViewWithAVPlayer" function ,It can play.

Another: if I use this code"

```
        skView.presentScene(scene01)
       //self.view.addSubview(skView)
```

（Comments the second） And user "player.play()"  it can play (I can hear the sound).
But if I use this:

```
           skView.presentScene(scene01)
       self.view.addSubview(skView)
```

I also can see the first frame.and can not run anymore.

Is there something I do is wrong? Help Me! Thanks A lot.

Comment: I got the same/similar problem too. Whenever i init a SKVideoNode with a AVPlayer, it just shows the first frame, play does "nothing". If initing SKVideoNode using videoNodeWithVideoFileNamed, the video can be played but unfortunately we can't control the playback really.

Answer (score 1):

For no reason. You just can't use AVPlayer to control SKVideoNode's play or pause. but you can control monitor its play state via AVPlayer.

To play or pause a SKVideoNode, you have to use

`video.play() / video.pause() // (video you declared here is the instance of SKVideoNode)`