# SKVideoNode.pause() not pausing video

Tags: ios, swift, video, avplayer, skvideonode

I have an SKVideoNode, like so -

```
let path = "videoURL";
let url = NSURL(string: path);
let asset = AVURLAsset(URL: url!,options: nil);
let playerItem = AVPlayerItem(asset: asset);
let playerThree = AVPlayer(playerItem: playerItem);
let videoNode = SKVideoNode(AVPlayer: playerThree);
```

Which I want to pause on a button press, the button looks like this -

```
var isPausedThreeSixty : Bool = false;

@IBAction func threesixty(sender: AnyObject){
    if (videoPlayer == 1) { // check if video player is the 360 videoplayer
        if(isPausedThreeSixty == false){ //check if video is paused, if not pause video on click
            videoNode?.pause(); // pause video node
            print("pause player");
            isPausedThreeSixty == true;
        }else{ //if app runs else, video is paused, proceed to unpause.
            videoNode?.play();
            print("play player");
            isPausedThreeSixty = false;
        }
    }
}
```

My code does print the `pause player` and `play player` but it just won't pause the video, I've also read that I should pause the AVPlayer instead, but when calling `playerThree.pause();` the video isn't being paused either.

see - [How do I control playback of a video in an iOS Sprite Kit SKVideoNode?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27027648/how-do-i-control-playback-of-a-video-in-an-ios-sprite-kit-skvideonode)

and

[AVPlayer play SKVideoNode video ,I just can not control the playback](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26541073/avplayer-play-skvideonode-video-i-just-can-not-control-the-playback)

Why are multiple SO answers saying that calling `.pause` and `.play` on the SKVideoNode works, even though when implementing it, it doesn't actually work.

After pausing this video I want to be able to swap to a new video player, I've got that working.. it's just that I can't delete or pause this video player.

see - https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/28470  according to this post AVPlayer rate is being overwritten, and thus a SKVideoNode cannot be paused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had to pause the AVPlayerItem so -

```
playerThree.pause();
```

Did the trick.